# Issue returning an abstract type with a higher rank trait bound

Tags: generics, rust, reference, lifetime

I'm trying to write a generic trait for sending messages between processes. The simplified version of it looks like this:

```rust
trait Sender<T> {
    fn send_msg(&mut self, to: u64, body: T) -> Result<()>;
}
```

I want to be able to send messages that contain references, so as to avoid copying data:

```rust
#[derive(Serialize)]
enum MsgBody<'a> {
    Success,
    Fail(Error),
    Write { offset: u64, buf: &'a [u8] },
}
```

However I've run into an issue where the type parameter `T` can only refer to a single lifetime, preventing references of any lifetime from being used. To illustrate this consider this dummy implementation of `Sender<T>`:

```rust
struct SenderImpl<T>(PhantomData<T>);

impl<T: Serialize> Sender<T> for SenderImpl<T> {
    fn send_msg(&mut self, to: u64, body: T) -> Result<()> {
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

Now if I try to return a sender that will work for any lifetime parameter

```rust
fn ref_sender() -> impl for<'a> Sender<MsgBody<'a>> {
    SenderImpl(PhantomData)
}
```

then I get a compilation error because the type parameter `T` is not generic over all possible lifetimes:

```
error: implementation of `Sender` is not general enough
  --> src/lib.rs:29:5
   |
29 |     SenderImpl(PhantomData)
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ implementation of `Sender` is not general enough
   |
   = note: `SenderImpl<MsgBody<'2>>` must implement `Sender<MsgBody<'1>>`, for any lifetime `'1`...
   = note: ...but it actually implements `Sender<MsgBody<'2>>`, for some specific lifetime `'2`
```

The error makes sense but I'm not sure how to express what I want. What I'd like to say is this

```rust
fn ref_sender() -> impl for<'a> Sender<MsgBody<'a>> {
    SenderImpl(PhantomData::<for<'a> MsgBody<'a>>)
}
```

but of course `for<'a> MsgBody<'a>` is not actually a type.

I can work-around this by using `MsgBody` in the `Sender` trait rather than making it generic (you can see that [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=dda6798b62078e119a5339e45bb131c0)). I don't like this solution though as it sacrifices flexibility.

Is there a way to get the generic `Sender<T>` to work with types that have a lifetime parameter?

Edit: Here's the code used in this question:
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0aac9134639e9593698bfe9da7722d9f

Comment: how could you return a thing tie a lifetime without this lifetime tie to some argument of the function like https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7b0a3a94c79659d4c793efec6ef0ca6f ? The lifetime come from no where. This would never compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making the trait generic, move the generic type parameter to `send_msg`:

```rust
trait Sender {
    fn send_msg<T: Serialize>(&mut self, to: u64, body: T) -> Result<()>;
}
```

Then every call to `send_msg` can use a different lifetime parameter. The full solution is [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=496c865a0b83685852d79a32191d3ed3).

Comment: Ah, I figured this was discounted since I thought you only wanted to send specific types, just with different lifetime parameters. But if this works for you, it is certainly the simplest.

Comment: This is probably the simplest way to resolve the issue I encountered, but if you want to restrict the types which can be sent, take a look at @kmdreko's  answer below.

Answer (score 0):

As you've noted, `&T` needs a lifetime to be a complete type and `for<'a> &'a T` doesn't exist. The concrete problem is that `SenderImpl<T>` must have a complete type `T` and only implements `Sender` with that type.

You can workaround this by avoiding references in `SenderImpl<T>` (by making `T = [u8]`) and allow it to implement `Sender<&T>` for any lifetime:

```
struct SenderImpl<T: ?Sized>(PhantomData<T>);

impl<'a, T: Serialize + ?Sized> Sender<&'a T> for SenderImpl<T> {
    fn send_msg(&mut self, to: u64, body: &'a T) -> Result<()> {
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

> This approach doesn't seem to work in the case where T has it's own lifetime parameter.

You could also make it generic over any specific type with lifetimes, just `SenderImpl` won't have a specific type associated with it beyond what the trait implementation implies:

```
struct SenderImpl;

impl<'a> Sender<MsgBody<'a>> for SenderImpl {
    fn send_msg(&mut self, to: u64, body: MsgBody<'a>) -> Result<()> {
        Ok(())
    }
}

fn ref_sender() -> impl for<'a> Sender<MsgBody<'a>> {
    SenderImpl
}
```

Or, similarly to the self-answer, you can implement `Sender<T>` for any type. But like the above, `SenderImpl` obviously won't be specific to any in particular:

```
struct SenderImpl;

impl<T: Serialize> Sender<T> for SenderImpl {
    fn send_msg(&mut self, to: u64, body: T) -> Result<()> {
        Ok(())
    }
}

fn ref_sender() -> impl for<'a> Sender<MsgBody<'a>> {
    SenderImpl
}
```

Comment: That's a good solution for the case where the type `T` is a reference (I wrote out your the solution in the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ef8323b2ca0bbe6b9afb80d9861d0dc2)). However, this approach doesn't seem to work in the case where `T` has it's own lifetime parameter, which is the case I actually need. I've written out a better example of this [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0aac9134639e9593698bfe9da7722d9f) and I'll update my question with it.

Comment: @UserSpaceMan I've updated my answer. Even if your self-answer is probably better for your use-case, I'll leave mine here since it is still possible to do with a higher-ranked trait-bound if you or someone else needs it.

Comment: In my case I don't want to limit the types that can be sent, anything that can be serialized should be allowed. So I'm going to mark my answer as accepted. I do think that the last code snippet in your answer is a good example of how to do this if you want to require a specific type with a lifetime parameter.